# What is the easiest way to make an optional C extension for a python package?

Tags: python, setuptools, cython, python-c-extension

I've created a C extension that I'd like to enable in my Python package (using setuptools) only if a command line option is passed in.  What is the easiest way to do this?

I can't seem to find any straightforward ways of going about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ext_modules = []
if '--add-this' in sys.argv:
    ext_modules.append(Extension(...))
    sys.argv.remove('--add-this')
setup(...
      ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

This is hacky, but might be easiest. A more advanced approach would be to extend the Distribution class to support a flag, say `--with-modules` and then customize ext_modules inside finalize_options.

Answer (score 15):

There's actually a distribute/setuptools feature called "Features" that can be used for this. 
It's explicitly designed to have setup.py do different things based on `--with-xxx` and `--without-xxx` command line options.

- This [blog post](https://www.domenkozar.com/2010/07/07/hidden-gem-in-python-packaging-world/) gives a nice introduction, I can't find any better documentation at this time (besides the Distribute source - [the Feature class](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/src/f4170897eb2c/setuptools/dist.py#cl-664) and [features keyword](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/src/055afac65a20/setuptools/dist.py#cl-153)).
- The jinja project's [setup.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/setup.py) uses Features for your exact purpose, it might be a good template to work from.
- The simplejson [setup.py](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/0bcdf20cc525c1343b796cb8f247ea5213c6557e/setup.py#L110) also does something similar, except that it's coded to always try to build the C-extension feature it defines, and fall back gracefully to pure-python when building fails; this may also be useful for your purpose.

Comment: The lack of documentation for Feature might indicate their "essential deprecation - an experimental thing that turned out to be, well, a failed experiment": https://www.mail-archive.com/distutils-sig@python.org/msg12061.html